# How to style facebook button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with styling facebook login button with my app.

Example of my view:

```
<View style={{ ...styles.btnWrapper }}>
  <LoginButton
    onLoginFinished={(error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // TODO error message
      } else {
        debugger;
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
          const processRequest = new GraphRequest(
            `me/picture?redirect=0&height=500&width=500&type=normal`,
            null,
            this.getProfilePic,
          );
          new GraphRequestManager()
            .addRequest(processRequest)
            .start();
          this.onSuccessfulLogin(
            data?.userID!,
            data?.accessToken!,
          );
        });
      }
    }}
    style={{ ...styles.faceBtn }}
    // onLogoutFinished={() => alert('User logged out')}
  />
</View>
```

Here is the screen:

[image]

I tried:

```
btnWrapper: {
    width: 311,
    height: 46,
},
faceBtn: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    padding: 0,
},
```

But it takes only height and width. I need to put above text in the middle of button. Any advice ?

Comment: can u provide the JSX of the button

Comment: @batgerel.e I think Pain meant the JSX of LoginButton

Comment: @Rostyslav you mean `facebook.jsx` ?

Comment: It may be helpful if you could duplicate a reproducible code example in an Expo snack and share here.

Comment: on the style object `faceBtn: {}` try add `justifyContent: center; alignItems: center`, it might help, it might not depends on the `LoginButton` structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have the full control to style the `LoginButton` which is provided by fbsdk, if you want a custom button you can always make your own and use that with `LoginManager`. Here is the sample code below

import the required features

`const { LoginButton,LoginManager,AccessToken} = require("react-native-fbsdk");`

create a custom button with your style

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._loginFacebook}>
<Text> Login with facebook </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

login with facebook

```
 _loginFacebook = () => {
    LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile", "email"]).then(
    result => {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        console.log("Login cancelled");
      } else {
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
          .then(data => {
          
           
            //do anything with data.accessToken
            
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("Login fail with error: " + error);
    }
  );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know how the LoginButton component looks inside, but React Native uses Flexbox for layout.

You could use `alignSelf` on the "Continue with Facebook" text. Refer to the documentation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#align-self).

If this is not your component and you're importing it from another library, this looks like a bug to me. You should open an issue on the libraries issue page.